# Help with easyocr fine tuned model inference

Tags: python, pytorch, ocr

I have trained a custom model, I have the yaml file and pth file and the py file in the correct directories. But now I face this error

````
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
1 import easyocr
----> 2 reader = easyocr.Reader(lang_list=['en'],recog_network='best_accuracy')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/easyocr/recognition.py in get_recognizer(recog_network, network_params, character, separator_list, dict_list, model_path, device, quantize)
164 else:
165 model_pkg = importlib.import_module(recog_network)
--> 166 model = model_pkg.Model(num_class=num_class, **network_params)
167
168 if device == 'cpu':

TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_class'
```
````

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Your question is not clear: if you installed the library, you must have all the code needed. Please explain your issue more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have fine tuned the TPS-ResNet-BiLSTM-Attn-case-sensitive model with my own data, now I have the pth file, py file( I solved the py file issue) and yaml file to use my custom model. But I am having trouble in inference of the model. I put them in the right directories as mentioned in the documentation but it gives an error rn. I have updated the question so kindly help me in solving the error.

Comment: @Erwan I followed all the instructions here. https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR/blob/master/custom_model.md

Comment: I don't know the library, it's very specific. The error looks like a bug in the library code, so I would suggest to open an issue on their github repo.

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks for your time

Comment: Finally i found a person fineTuning existing model. How did u fine tune the model? I want to fine tune english_g2.pth text recognition model or None-VGG-BiLSTM-CTC.pth. I have all other models like CRNN-PyTorchCTC,TPS-ResNet-BiLSTM-Attn etc. but irony is that models doesn't come with other 2 files and i don't know how to it.

Comment: What was the solution? Could you please share an example of custom yaml file?